# Custom Web Clients using Azure AD for Authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth, office365, o365rwsclient

If I'm writing ASP.NET Web App that uses Azure Active Directory for authentication, how should I perform authentication of the RWS Client Calls in order to avoid double authentication?

I've noticed that RWS is using Basic Authentication on the Web Service side, but Azure AD can provide me with OAuth2 token. Can I use that OAuth2 token to connect to RWS like it can be used to access EWS?

(sample is here: http://www.jeremythake.com/2014/08/using-the-exchange-online-ews-api-with-office-365-api-via-azure-ad/ )

Comment: Unfortunately, the Office 365 reporting web service (RWS) does not support OAuth.

Comment: @femtoRgon: Could you re-edit the tag: If you have to keep one tag, then keep o365rwsclient and remove office365rwsclient. Because we o365rwsclient to track question on SO. Thanks